# r - replacing groups of elements in vector

Tags: r, vector, replace, element

I am trying to replace all the groups of elements in a vector that sum up to zero with NAs.
The size of each group is 3. For instance:

```
a = c(0,0,0,0,2,3,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0)
```

should be finally:

```
c(NA,NA,NA,0,2,3,1,0,2,NA,NA,NA,0,1,2,NA,NA,NA)
```

Until now, I have managed to find the groups having the sum equal to zero via:

```
b = which(tapply(a,rep(1:(length(a)/3),each=3),sum) == 0)
```

which yields `c(1,4,6)`

I then calculate the starting indexes of the groups in the vector via: `b <- b*3-2`.
Probably there is a more elegant way, but this is what I've stitched together so far.
Now I am stuck at "expanding" the vector of start indexes, to generate a sequence of the elements to be replaced. For instance, if vector `b` now contains `c(1,10,16)`, I will need a sequence `c(1,2,3,10,11,12,16,17,18)` which are the indexes of the elements to replace by NAs.
If you have any idea of a solution without a `for` loop or even a more simple/elegant solution for the whole problem, I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Marius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
a[as.logical(ave(a, 0:(length(a)-1) %/% 3, 
             FUN = function(x) sum(x) == 0))] <- NA
a
#  [1] NA NA NA  0  2  3  1  0  2 NA NA NA  0  1  2 NA NA NA
```

The `0:(length(a)-1) %/% 3` creates groups of your desired length (in this case, 3) and `ave` is used to check whether those groups add to 0 or not.

Answer (score 2):

To designate the values to the same group turn your vector into (a three-row)  matrix. You can then calculate the column-wise sums and compare with 0. The rest is simple.

```
a <- c(0,0,0,0,2,3,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0)
a <- as.integer(a)
is.na(a) <- rep(colSums(matrix(a, 3L)) == 0L, each = 3L)
a
#[1] NA NA NA  0  2  3  1  0  2 NA NA NA  0  1  2 NA NA NA
```

Note that I make the comparison with integers to indicate that if your vector is not an integer, you need to consider [this FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9508558/1412059).

Comment: @Marius My answer is a one-liner too (actually it's shorter than Ananda's code) and can be made more general by using `apply`. Probably, it's also faster. (This is just a reply to your remarks. I don't need the tick mark.)

Answer (score 0):

Or using `gl`, `ave` and `all`

```
n <- length(a)
a[ave(!a, gl(n, 3, n), FUN=all)] <- NA
a
#[1] NA NA NA  0  2  3  1  0  2 NA NA NA  0  1  2 NA NA NA
```